# How to handle variables that contain ";"?

Tags: bash, debian

I have a configuration file that contains lines like "hallo;welt;" and i want to do a grep on this file.
Whenever i try something like `grep "$1;$2" my.config` or `echo "$1;$2` of even line="$1;$2" my script fails with something like:

> : command not found95: line 155: =hallo...

How can i tell bash to ignore ; while evaluating "..." blocks?

EDIT: an example of my code.

```
# find entry
$line=$(grep "$1;$2;" $PERMISSIONSFILE)
# splitt line
reads=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f3)
writes=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f4)
admins=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f5)

# do some stuff on the permissions

# replace old line with new line
nline="$1;$2;$reads;$writes;$admins"
sed -i "s/$line/$nline/g" $TEMPPERM
```

my script should be called like this: sh script "table" "a.b.*.>"

EDIT: another, simpler example

```
$test=$(grep "$1;$2;" temp.authorization.config)
```

the temp file:

```
table;pattern;read;write;stuff
```

the call sh test.sh table pattern results in: `: command not foundtable;pattern;read;write;stuff`

Comment: Use an escape / backslash before the semi-colon. `\;`

Comment: Please show a simple script that shows exactly your problem.  Using double quotes should prevent semi-colons being interpreted.

Comment: added a simple one liner that results in the error.

Comment: Your `$test=$(grep ...)` line is erroneous; you do not use the `$` on the LHS of the assignment (or, at least, not until you're not asking this question; I've done stuff like that once or twice in the last quarter century, but not often).

Comment: The same problem afflicts your `$line=$(grep ...)` code.

Comment: i have 15 lines like 'test=$(grep ...' and only one of them has the $ in front of the variable... i just didn't see this. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `$` on the left side of an assignment in bash -- if you do it'll substitute the current value of the variable rather than assigning to it.  That is, use:

```
test=$(grep "$1;$2;" temp.authorization.config)
```

instead of:

```
$test=$(grep "$1;$2;" temp.authorization.config)
```

Edit: also, variable expansions should be in double-quotes unless there's a good reason otherwise.  For example, use:

```
reads=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f3)
```

instead of:

```
reads=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f3)
```

This doesn't matter for semicolons, but does matter for spaces, wildcards, and a few other things.

Comment: I can't believe so many answers fail to point out this, the first and most obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A `;` inside quotes has no meaning at all for bash. However, if $1 contains a doublequote itself, then you'll end up with

```
grep "something";$2"
```

which'll be parsed by bash as two separate commands:

```
grep "something"   ;     other"
^---command 1----^    ^----command 2---^
```

Show please show exactly what your script is doing around the spot the error is occurring, and what data you're feeding into it.

Comment: Your explanation of double quotes in variable values is inaccurate.  Try `bash -x xx.sh '"something"' happened` using the `xx.sh` script from my answer to see this.  Your first sentence is accurate, though.

Comment: seem like the problems start when i try to assign the result of grep to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example:

```
$ cat file.txt
hello;welt;
hello;world;
hell;welt;  
$ cat xx.sh
grep "$1;$2" file.txt
$ bash -x xx.sh hello welt
+ grep 'hello;welt' file.txt
hello;welt;
$
```

You have not yet classified your problem accurately.

---

> If you try to assign the result of grep to a variable (like I do) your example breaks.

Please show what you mean.  Using the same data file as before and doing an assignment, this is the output I get:

```
$ cat xx.sh
grep "$1;$2" file.txt
output=$(grep "$1;$2" file.txt)
echo "$output"
$ bash -x xx.sh hello welt
+ grep 'hello;welt' file.txt
hello;welt;
++ grep 'hello;welt' file.txt
+ output='hello;welt;'
+ echo 'hello;welt;'
hello;welt;
$
```

Seems to work for me.  It also demonstrates why the question needs an explicit, complete, executable, minimal example so that we can see what the questioner is doing that is different from what people answering the question think is happening.

---

I see you've provided some sample code:

```
# find entry
$line=$(grep "$1;$2;" $PERMISSIONSFILE)
# splitt line
reads=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f3)
writes=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f4)
admins=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f5)
```

The line `$line=$(grep ...)` is wrong.  You should omit the `$` before `line`.  Although it is syntactically correct, it means 'assign to the variable whose name is stored in `$line` the result of the `grep` command'.  That is unlikely to be what you had in mind.  It is, occasionally, useful.  However, those occasions are few and far between, and only for people who know what they're doing and who can document accurately what they're doing.

For safety if nothing else, I would also enclose the `$line` values in double quotes in the `echo` lines.  It may not strictly be necessary, but it is simple protective programming.

The changes lead to:

```
# find entry
line=$(grep "$1;$2;" $PERMISSIONSFILE)
# split line
reads=$( echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f3)
writes=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f4)
admins=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f5)
```

The rest of your script was fine.

Comment: if you try to assign the result of grep to a variable (like i do) your example breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to read a semicolon-delimited file, identify a line starting with 'table;pattern;' where table is a string you specify and pettern is a regular expression `grep` will understand. Once the line is identified you wish to replaced the 3rd, 4th and 5th fields with different data and write the updated line back to the file.

Does this sound correct?

If so, try this code

```
#!/bin/bash

in_table="$1"
in_pattern="$2"
file="$3"

while IFS=';' read -r -d$'\n' tuple pattern reads writes admins ; do
    line=$(cut -d: -f1<<<"$tuple")
    table=$(cut -d: -f2<<<"$tuple")

    # do some stuff with the variables
    # e.g., update the values
    reads=1
    writes=2
    admins=12345

    # replace the old line with the new line
    sed -i'' -n $line'{i\
'"$table;$pattern;$reads;$writes;$admins"'
;d;}' "$file"
done < <(grep -n '^'"${in_table}"';'"${in_pattern}"';' "${file}")
```

I chose to update by line number here to avoid problems of unknown characters in the left hand of the substitution.